# Xampp vhost page 'not safe'

Tags: xampp, vhosts

I've been playing around with xampp.I've tried to set up a vhost and followed all the steps. but now my local domain response is as followed

I've added the domain in the vhost-conf. also have I checked if it is used in the config file.

I've used this tut: https://jonathannicol.com/blog/2012/03/11/configuring-virtualhosts-in-xampp-on-mac/

[image]

Comment: Well, looks like the certificate you use is invalid for the domain you use.

Comment: How do I fix this?

Comment: By creating a valid certificate that matches your domain (host name). You did not tell us what host name you configured for your virtual host, nor did you tell us how you created or purchased your certificate. So we cannot really help very much here. Just one question: you _did_ install a certificate, didn't you?

Comment: Its on my localhost, I've configured localhost and ddd.dev following the tutorial. I've not been installing any certificates

Comment: Any https connection will _always_ and correctly be considered "unsafe" by any sane browser if the certificate used for the encryption is invalid or does not match the requested host name. If you did not install any certificate then a "snake oil" certificate bundled with the http server software (apache in your case) is used, that one allows encryption (thus https), but cannot be considered valid for obvious reasons. You either need to use `http` instead of `https`, or install that certificate as trustworthy in each browser or create and setup a valid certificate for a domain owned by you.

Comment: I'd say you want to read a bit about how `https` actually works, especially the certificate detail. You cannot get around that if you really want to use encrypted communication.